Does ん in Japanese encapsulate both the "Finland" and "Finger" "n" sounds (depending on the word)?
"Finger" and "Finland" have their n's make a different sound (finger has the back of the tongue touch the mouth roof, whereas finland uses the front of the tongue). In Hindi and Sanskrit, these two n's each explicitly get their own character. In English, the character "n" is overloaded to express both sounds, depending on the word.
Is Japanese similar to English? Is ん overloaded to express both sounds? Off the top of my head, I think that インド is like "Finland", and 暗黒{あんこく} is like "Finger", but that could be just my misunderstanding.
Fwiw, the basis for me believing the Japanese might not be like English (and ん is only ever like "Finland") is that the system of かな were literally designed by an Indian monk (where none of the phonetic letters are overloaded to give multiple sounds), and traditionally, none of the かな are overloaded to make multiple sounds (outside of う being often used to extend the お vowel).

This question is similar to: Why does the g tends to sound more like a m or n?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57116/7810

Read also "Moraic nasal" section of Japanese phonology.

Regarding "none of the かな are overloaded to make multiple sounds ..." claim, it is mostly true for modern orthography for modern Japanese, but it was not true in the past (mostly Middle Japanese period). Examples: voicedness marker was not consistently used (e.g. か meant /ka/ or /ga/); after /p/ split into /p/ and /ɸ/, there was no distinction in orthography for some centuries (は meant /pa/ or /ɸa/, besides /wa/); there were nasal vowels (e.g. かう meant /kau/ or /kaũ/; 方法 was /paũpau/ at some time); there was /t./ distinct from /ti/ ~ /t͡ɕi/ and /tu/ ~ /t͡su/ (e.g. かつ meant /kat͡su/ or /kat/).
